# Apex class to be used for both with and without sharing

Tags: apex, apex-sharing

I have created a selector class on Campaign object to be used in `with sharing` context like below:

```
public with sharing class CampaignSelector {

    public static Map<Id, Campaign> getCampaigns() {
        Map<Id, Campaign> campaignsByIds = new Map<Id, Campaign>([
                SELECT Id,
                        Name
                FROM Campaign
                WHERE Start_Date__c <= TODAY
                AND End_Date__c >= TODAY
        ]);
        return campaignsByIds;
    }
}
```

Now there is a situation where I have to use the same query in `without sharing` context. I can create a new class defined as `without sharing` and then add the selector query. But is there any other cleaner approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same requirement once. So what we did is we had a class that executed the query to be abstract and we created instances of its successors, that determined the sharing model. This way you still only one query to maintain and a single entry point, but you're free to switch the sharing context on flight.

For your case this will look something like this:

```
public class CampaignSelector {

    private static CampaignDataService dataService {
        get {
            if (null == dataService) {
                // use with sharing by default
                dataService = new WithSharing();
            }
            return dataService;
        }
        set;
    }

    public static Map<Id, Campaign> getCampaigns() {
        return dataService.getCampaigns();
    }

    public static void switchSharing(Boolean useSharing) {
        // this method is used to switch sharing model
        if (useSharing) {
            dataService = new WithSharing();
        } else {
            dataService = new WithoutSharing();
        }
    }

    private abstract class CampaignDataService {
        public Map<Id, Campaign> getCampaigns() {
            Map<Id, Campaign> campaignsByIds = new Map<Id, Campaign>([
                    SELECT Id,
                            Name
                    FROM Campaign
                    WHERE Start_Date__c <= TODAY
                    AND End_Date__c >= TODAY
            ]);
            return campaignsByIds;
        }
    }

    private with sharing class WithSharing extends CampaignDataService {}
    private without sharing class WithoutSharing extends CampaignDataService {}
}
```

The query is still can be executed by calling `CampaignSelector. getCampaigns()`. By default it will be executed `with sharing`. To switch the sharing context you need to call `CampaignSelector.switchSharing(false)` - this will init dataService as an instance of `WihtoutSharing` and execute the query in `without sharing` context. You can switch back to `with sharing` in the same transaction by calling `CampaignSelector.switchSharing(true)`.

The problem with static methods is that they block you from using inheritance and other cool OOP stuff

Comment: This is good approach. I think I have used this as well.

Comment: The thing is it boils down to same principal of using inner classes to solve the issue

Comment: Yup. It just makes it easy to maintain by reducing code duplication

Comment: @snl before calling `CampaignSelector.getCampaigns()` call `CampaignSelector. switchSharing(false)`. This will intialize `dataService` as `WithoutSharing` context and the query will be executed in `without sharing` context. Updated the answer with that info

Comment: @blank Thank you!

Comment: @snl Also, see [my example](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/291791/2984) on this technique as well. It may give you some other ideas of what's possible.

Comment: The example provided in this answer will only work if you call a method in the derived class that returns `getCampaigns()` from the base class. Simply declaring a sharing mode on the derived classes will have no effect by itself.

Comment: @geeljire That's what public method `CampaignSelector.getCampaigns()` does. It incapsulates calls to the inner derived classes. And `dataService` controls whether with or without sharing derived class is used.

Comment: @nchursin, that part makes sense. What I'm saying is the declaration itself is not sufficient to switch modes if you're invoking a method in the parent class. In that case, the parent class's sharing mode will take effect because the location of the method also matters, not just the class definition. In fact, b/c the declaration is omitted on the other classes, the sharing mode that takes effect in your code is actually the mode of whatever calls `CampaignSelector`. In short, you have to call a method on the derived class for the declarations to work.

Comment: @geeljire could you please provide a link to a git repo with a test to prove your point? I disagree with your reasoning, because method calls only inherit sharing rules as you mentioned when declaration is omitted. But the callstack here is caller (whatever sharing) -> CampaignSelector.getCampaigns (inherit) -> WithSharing (override to with sharing) or WithoutSharing (override to without sharing). So basically the sharing inheritance is breaking at the last call

Comment: Folks, can somebody tell me what am I missing here? I made a very similar implementation of this example but it simply doesn't work: https://gist.github.com/sauloefo/bdc7fa0500a6674977e7f8744ff7aac8

Comment: If it worth to mention, I'm using this selector from a AuraEnabled method declared in a classed defined as inherited sharing.

Answer (score 4):

One way would be to use inherited sharing instead of specifying the class using with or without sharing.

```
public inherited sharing class CampaignSelector {

    public static Map<Id, Campaign> getCampaigns() {
        Map<Id, Campaign> campaignsByIds = new Map<Id, Campaign>([
                SELECT Id,
                        Name
                FROM Campaign
                WHERE Start_Date__c <= TODAY
                AND End_Date__c >= TODAY
        ]);
        return campaignsByIds;
    }
}
```

Now if you call the class from without sharing class it will run in system mode.

And if you call the class from the with sharing it will execute in with sharing mode.

> If you have a same class that needs to run in with sharing and without sharing , create an inner class  using without sharing. Call your logic from the inner class to run in system context.

Comment: Well, the class from where I am calling this selector class is in 'with sharing' context.

Comment: You will need another inner class which uses without sharing for your scenario and call from there

Comment: This approach is harder to maintain. You will need to have inner classes in every place where you need to use without sharing context. It is better to have a single point which determines the sharing context at the selector class itself