# Why does adding a Queueable cause an INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY error?

Tags: community, files, queue, queueable-apex

I have code that inserts a `ContentVersion` (a File) that is run under a "Customer Community Login" license inside a Community/Experience. That works fine.

I now have an optional asynchronous layer that wraps that code in a `Queueable` that is started via a `System.enqueueJob`. This version fails with:

> INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, You do not have the
> level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested.
> Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access
> is necessary.: [NetworkId]

At first I thought this [Queueable apex invoked from triggers doesn't inherit sharing correctly](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/308527/queueable-apex-invoked-from-triggers-doesnt-inherit-sharing-correctly) might be the cause but changing the `Queueable` to be `without sharing` did not fix the problem as I hoped it might.

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you need to send the `NetworkId`. `Network.getNetworkId` returns `null` during queuable invocation.

So, it is necessary to pass around or query the `NetworkId` as soon as you introduce async indirection.

See this code for reference: [ConvertAttachmentsToFilesService](https://github.com/douglascayers/sfdc-convert-attachments-to-chatter-files/blob/master/src/classes/ConvertAttachmentsToFilesService.cls#L130-L133): it contains an instance to hold the value of `NetworkId` given the queuable context looses it.

This caused a big refactor for this library based on their [Issue #9](https://github.com/DouglasCAyers/sfdc-convert-attachments-to-chatter-files/issues/9).

Comment: Yes from a quick test of hard-coding the Network Id this looks like the problem. So it is not only the sharing context that is lost across the async calls but this Network Id too. In the multiple package code I work on, this is going to be painful to address.

Comment: Agreed, one solution for us might be to query `NetworkMember` on that scenario, but this still ugly, but the flip side is that you can avoid packaging multiple packages (at least not required any sort of global).

Comment: Thanks for all your help here Jeferson.