# Does NetworkMember solve the problem of assigning the Network Id in Communities/Experiences?

Tags: community, user, files, asynchronous, identity

See:

[Why does adding a Queueable cause an INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY error?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/336325/why-does-adding-a-queueable-cause-an-insufficient-access-on-cross-reference-enti)

for some background. That results in the need to set the `NetworkId` (there is one of these per Community) on the `ContentVersion` object.

Passing that Id explicitly can be awkward, and given the [NetworkMember](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_networkmember.htm) object, a query:

```
select NetworkId from NetworkMember where select MemberId = :UserInfo.getUserId()
```

will return the zero or more relevant NetworkIds.

In my experience, a Username is unique to a Community, meaning the above would return the required single NetworkId. But are there other Community setups where the same UserId applies to more than one Community?

Comment: A colleague just pointed to this [Configure SAML for Experience Cloud Sites](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.networks_auth_configure_saml.htm&type=5) that I think means yes the same UserId can apply to more than one community.

Comment: I think is technically possible to add the same [profiles, permission sets, and users on multiple communities](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.networks_customize_members.htm&type=5), but that gets very messy. So, probably the best is to keep it separate. I have worked on deploying multiple communities under the same org but back then they used separate profiles, but I don't know the usage in the wild.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm you'd get as many records in `NetworkMember` as there are communities the user has access to for a single `MemberId`. It's as simple as Jefferson mentioned with his link for a given profile/permission set. You might have to add another filter, technically, like `Network.Name` to be absolutely certain it's the right one or re-evaluate whether passing NetworkId might be the best option.

Comment: Hi @JefersonChaves post as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Hi @KrisGoncalves post as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked in my current org as we do assign users to multiple communities and the query below

```
select NetworkId 
from NetworkMember 
where select MemberId = :UserInfo.getUserId()
```

Returns a row for each community the user is associated with.

As mentioned by @JeffersonChaves, [adding members](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.networks_customize_members.htm&type=5) to your community is as simple as adding their profile or permission set to have access to it. This means a given user, based on their profile and/or permission set, could be a member of multiple communities. Whether this is common, I do not know - but, it is possible and have seen this setup in multiple orgs.

Based on that info, you'll either have to add another filter to specify the community you're interested in by passing the Community name to your queueable/code:

```
select NetworkId 
from NetworkMember 
where select MemberId = :UserInfo.getUserId() AND Network.Name = :communityName
```

Or stick with passing in the NetworkId to use in the query.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `NetworkMember` solves the problem of which users are part of a given Community/Experience.

However it is technically possible to add the same [profiles, permission sets, and users on multiple communities](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.networks_customize_members.htm&type=5), but that gets very messy.

So, probably the best is to keep it separate. I have worked on deploying multiple communities under the same org but back then they used separate profiles, but I don't know the usage in the wild.